# Spark Streaming - StandAlone Mode (cleanup not deleting data in work folder for each app for each batch)

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-standalone

In Streaming have set these parameters as below
    spark.worker.cleanup.enabled true
    spark.worker.cleanup.interval 60
    spark.worker.cleanup.appDataTtl 90

This clears out already killed spark batch/streaming jobs data in work/app-2016*/(1,2,3,4,5,6,...) folders. But on running Spark Streaming job the history data in the current app-* is not deleted. Since we are using Kafka-Spark connector jar,for every micro batch it copies this jar with app jar and stderr,stdout results on each folders(work/app-2016*/(1,2,3,4,5,6,...) . This itself is eating up lot of memory as Kafka-Spark connector is an uber jar and is around 15 MB and in a day it coming to 100 GB .

Is there a way to delete data from current running Spark Streaming job  or we should do some scripting for that...?

Comment: *Since we are using Kafka-Spark connector jar, for every micro batch it copies this jar with app jar and stderr,stdout results on each folders* That makes no sense. The JAR should only be copied once at the beginning of job submittion, not for every micro-batch. Perhaps you're seeing log files blow up?

Comment: Nope its adding Kafka-Spark jar in each directory of each microbatch and we are using PySpark.